# Could not find builder-7.0.0-alpha09.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have a problem with the newest android studio version.
android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 canary 9
The problem I have is this.

```
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find builder-7.0.0-alpha09.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.0-alpha09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.0.0-alpha09/builder-7.0.0-alpha09.jar
```

My android studio isn't offline mode and I cleared my cache But my problem, not fix, Is it possible to download and add it manually?
Or any other way

I'm so sorry for my English.